# Does motorola milestone work in these rangers

Tags: motorola-milestone

I want to move between mobile providers in my country.
Its seems as though the mobile provider I wish to move to only supports these ranges:
850 and 2100 mghz.

Does the motorola milestone support these ranges?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [gsmarena](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_milestone-3001.php):

> 2G Network    GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900
>
> 3G Network    HSDPA 900 / 2100
>
> UMTS 850 / 1900 - American version

Answer (score 2):

A simple Wikipedia search would have brought the answer:

### Compatible networks (for Motorola Milestone / Droid)

- **US Version:** dual band CDMA2000/EV-DO Rev. A 800/1900 MHz
- **European version:** quad band GSM, UMTS @ 900/2100MHz
- **N.A. GSM version:** quad band GSM, UMTS @ 850/1900 MHz

<sup>[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_droid)</sup>

where quad band means support for 850, 1900 MHz and 900, 1800 MHz.